# Jquery Datatables get row data on button click

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

i want to get specific row columns data on button click . here my code

```
var oTable = $('#grid').dataTable({

        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging": false,
        'aaData': dtData,
        'bPaginate': false,
        'bInfo': false,
        "ordering": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        'bFilter': true,
        destroy: true,
    "aoColumns": [null,null,null,null,

        {
            "mData": null,
            "bSortable": false,
            "mRender": function (o) { return '<a href="">'+"<img src='images/gridchart.png'></img>" +'</a>'; }
        },
        {
            "targets": [5],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false
        },
    {
        "targets": [6],
        "visible": false,
         "searchable": false
    }

    ]
}).rowGrouping();
```

the problem is that the two last columns are not added to the dom at all, so i cannot retrieve their respective values

any help is welcome

Comment: Show your html too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the last 2 row values as data attributes of the link like so:

```
'mRender': function (data, type, full) {
    return '<a data-col4=\'' + full[4] + '\' data-col5=\'' + full[5] + '\' href="">'+"<img src='images/gridchart.png'></img>" +'</a>'; 
}
```

The `full` argument is the datasource for the datatable row, so even thought the values aren't displayed, they're still available.

You would have to use jQuery to retrieve the values like this:

```
$('#grid tbody').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var col4Val = $(this).data('col4');
   var col5Val = $(this).data('col5');
   // you would then redirect to the link using window.location.href, adding the col4 & col5 values as querystring parameters
}
```

Or, you could add the parameters to the url when you render the link - you don't have anything in the `href` so I've assumed you're handing this with a jQuery click event.